# Using SSH from inside VMWare

Tags: wireless-networking, svn, vmware-player, xubuntu

I have to use use svn+ssh protocol to commit files to a remote repository using internet. However, with a Xubuntu (14.10) in VMware Player, I am not able to do so. However, there is no problem in using it from the host OS. How do I solve this?

It was suggested in different context (while connecting to guest from host using Putty or something) to use Bridge Connection rather than NAT. When I change to Bridge, I cannot connect to internet (the wifi is not shown), so no way I can use ssh.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ssh or svn. It's just getting the networking working.  e.g. try pinging and if it works or not.  I don't recall if it's vmware or virtualbox but one has an issue with bridge mode and wifi. Try using a wired connection and see if the bridge mode suddenly works   (And once you have the networking working, then it has nothing to do with virtual machines)

Comment: and if you find it works wired with bridge mode,  i.e. when you plug the network cable in, then you have an interesting question there of what to do to get it working or as a workaround.

Comment: @barlop not even wired bridged mode is working, sadly.

Comment: well obviously test the network, see if you can ping

Comment: I can't ping either. (e.g. ping -c 4 google.com gives unknown host, or network is unreachable for i.p. address)

Comment: @barlop, the network is still not working with bridge connection, but ssh worked with NAT now (dont remember what I changed (except cable)). Thanks.

Comment: Your question loses value because while the answer was good and you accepted it, you didn't state what aspect of it solved it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you use DHCP settings on Xubuntu. (What `ifconfig` showing on Xubuntu? Did it got IP from host's network?)
Make sure VMware isn't blocked by host's firewall or by firewall in front of host. Try to ping first host IP from Xubuntu, then do the same fom host to Xubuntu then try to ping router/gateway from Xubuntu that stay in front of host machine.
If you can control network where host connected then better to use `bridge`, this way virtualised Xubuntu will be accessible and act as dedicate host on your network. Try to connect in this configuration from host to Xubuntu to be make sure it got own IP from DHCP of primary network where host connected.
Shouldn't be an issue, but try to run VMware with administrative privileges to make sure host don't block something.